# User can't remove symlink which owns

Tags: linux, debian, filesystems, symbolic-link, rm

I'm trying to remove symlink, although I have appropriate permission, the operation is denied (the user is called `capistrno`):

```
capistrno $ rm -f /var/www/app/current
rm: cannot remove `/var/www/app/current': Permission denied
```

the user should have all permissions to this file

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 capistrano capistrano 42 17. mar 13.09 /var/www/app/current -> /var/www/app/releases/20130317120932/

capistrno $ file /var/www/app/current
/var/www/app/current: symbolic link to `/var/www/app/releases/20130317120932'
```

Any idea what's wrong?

**EDIT:**

folder `/var/www/app`

```
$ ls -laF /var/www/app/
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 4 www-data   www-data 4096 17. mar 14.15 ./
drwxrwxr-x 4 capistrano www-data 4096 17. mar 00.01 ../
drwxrwxr-x 6 capistrano www-data 4096 17. mar 14.15 releases/
drwxrwxr-x 7 capistrano www-data 4096 17. mar 00.39 shared/
```

user `capistrano` belongs to this groups:

```
$ groups
capistrano www-data rvm
```

Comment: Please show the owner, group and permission of `/var/www/app`. It's the directory you need access to in order to add/remove files from it.

Comment: yeah, now I see it `chown -R capistrano /var/www/app` should fix it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you split your operation in 2 parts:

- 'unlink' the symbolic link
- 'rm' the unwanted directory

It is cleaner and less prone to errors. You will also get the exact errors, for each of those commands..

Answer (score 4):

Symlinks are always shown with **777** permissions and can be deleted by **root**, **owner** and **owner group** only.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you made a typo while sanitizing this post, You've assigned ownership and group to capistrano, while the user name is suposed to be capistrno.

capistrano =/= capistrno